# ReadAllLines().Count returns false answer

Tags: visual-studio

I have a *.txt file that I want to read into array. I used

```
lineCount = ReadAllLines(<FileName.txt>).Count
```

to get the number of lines of text in the txt file. It returned a value of 19862 when there are really 31434 lines of text in the file. The varialble 'lineCount' is dimensioned as a Long. The text file is just a test file and in the real world the files will be very much larger.

I am obviously doing something wrong here, can anyone say what it is?

Ben

Comment: Can you reduce the size of the file to reproduce it with a (much) smaller number of lines? Are there maybe empty lines?

Comment: I will try with a reduced file size and see what happens, for test purposes it is possible to do that. The files are AutoCAD DXF files which have an enormous number of lines to create a single graphical object, here is the code to create a circle:  
'code'
  0
CIRCLE
  5
13B1
330
1F
100
AcDbEntity
  8
0
100
AcDbCircle
 10
554.1749770801236
 20
515.459935942678
 30
0.0
 40
7.662642504481141
1001
AMSELS
1002
{
1000
This is a circle's XData
1002
}
'/code'
Each space is a new line. As you can see the lines are mostly very short, but some lines have 255 characters.

Ben

Comment: I have found the problem. The last line of the text file was an empty line and when I removed that last empty line all worked perfectly. There are other empty lines in the file but they do not cause a problem.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the problem. The last line of the text file was an empty line and when I removed that last empty line all worked perfectly. There are other empty lines in the file but they do not cause a problem.